# How to access member variables of a constructor outside of it in php

Tags: php, class, constructor

I made the following example class

```
class a{

 function __construct(){
    $a =10;
    $b=9;
    }


}

$z=new a();
```

I would like to know how can I access $a and $b using the object(or by other means) to perform a single $a + $b addition. I know this can be done using the super global array but I would like to know are there any other methods to do this rather than declaring them global.

I know the code doesn't make much sense but doing it for example purposes

Answer (score 3):

Make those variables properties instead:

```
class a
{
    public $a;
    public $b;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = 10;
        $this->b = 9;
    }
}

$z = new a();
echo $z->a;
```

Better yet though, abstract your operation into a function:

```
echo $z->addProperties();

// Inside a class
public function addProperties() {
    return $this->a + $this->b;
}
```

Later on, when you want to add a third property that you need to add to your other two (or even subtract or multiply by), then all you have to do is change your `a` class, and not any code that actually uses it.

Answer (score 1):

By name constructors are used for any initialization that the object may need before it is used. So if you do the way you are doing

```
function __construct(){
    $a =10;
    $b=9;
    }
```

The variables $a & $b scope are limited to the function __construct().

You may need $a & $b as class variable rather than the function something as

```
class a{
 public $a;
 public $b;
 function __construct(){
    $this->a =10;
    $this->b=9;
 }
}

$z=new a();
// access a & b as
$z->a ; $z->b
```

The constructor here will do the initialization job of the variables when you instantiate the object.

Answer (score 0):

In your example there are two local variables in the function. You should create class fields to access them via object:

```
class a {

    public $a;
    public $b;

    function __construct() {
        $this->a = 10;
        $this->b = 9;
    }
}
```

$z = new a();

**echo $z->a;**

**echo $z->b;**

Comment: If you want to access them directly, you shouldn't make the properties private... make them public instead

Answer (score 0):

You can`t return in the cunstructor even if you do:

```
    class a{
     public $a;
     public $b;
     function __construct(){
        $this->a =10;
        $this->b=9;
        return 19;
     }
    }
$b = new a();
var_dump($b);
```

You would get an instance of a, thus you heve the alternatives:
make a new method:

```
<?php
function add()
{
   return $this->a+$this->b;
}
?>
```

Or generate getter`s (for both) =>

```
<?php
function getA()
{
   return $this->a;
}
?>
```

Or declare them public and access them:

```
$z->a+$z->b;
```

It depends on you`r app architecture or restrictions you might have or want to impose

Comment: I know function can be made, but wanted to do it through constructor. experimenting

Comment: Why would you do that? If you want set a new variable 'd' to the sum of A and B and access it or write a function to retrieve it.